# Route [posts.category] not defined

Tags: laravel-10, php-8.2

I'm learning Laravel 10 and trying to make a sub Route of my Route ressource posts.

in my web.php :

```
*// path: routes/web.php*

...
Route::ressource('posts', PostController::class)
  ->only(['index', 'store', 'category'])
  ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
...
```

in my PostController.php :

```
*// path: app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php*

...
public function category(): View
{
  return view('posts.category', [
    'posts' => Post::all(),
]);
}
...

*// still trying to show with specific category_id*
*// but that's not the problem*
```

in my category.blade.php :

```
*// path: resources/views/posts/category.blade.php*

<x-app-layout>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</x-app-layout>
```

and in my index.blade.php :

```
*// resources/views/categories/index.blade.php

<x-app-layout>
...
@foreach ($categories as $category)
  <a :href="{{ route('posts.category', ['category_id' => $category->id]) }}">
@endofreach
...
</x-app-layout>
```

but on categories/index.blade.php I get this error :
`Route [posts.category] not defined.`

Show the lists of posts based on category_id

Comment: It's `Route::resource`, not `Route::ressource`